# Can't get Serilog to write to a RollingFile log

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, serilog

I'm trying to use Serilog in a dotnet webapi app. I need logging to go to both the Console and a Rolling log file.

Everything is coming out to the Console but nothing is appearing in the rolling log file and I'm not getting any errors anywhere.

I have setup serilog in my code like so:

```
// in program.cs Main
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(BASEDIR)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .Build();
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .Enrich.With(new ThreadIdEnricher())
    .CreateLogger();

// startup.cs Configure
app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
```

And in appsetting.json I have

```
 {
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Async",
        "Args": {
          "configure": [
            {
              "Name": "Console",
              "Args": {
                "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} {Level:u1} TID:{ThreadId} {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}",
                "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.SystemConsoleTheme::Literate, Serilog.Sinks.Console"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Async",
        "Args": {
          "configure": [
            {
              "Name": "RollingFile",
              "Args": {
                "pathFormat": "c:\\logs\\{Date}.log",
                "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} {Level:u1} TID:{ThreadId} {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}",
                "buffered": false,
                "rollingInterval": "Serilog.RollingInterval.Day, Serilog.Sinks.File",
                "retainedFileCountLimit": 7
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried to change to static file name?
does the path exists?
it seems that the configuration on the readme from their github page is a bit differnt from yours:
https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file#user-content-json-appsettingsjson-configuration:~:text=node%2C%20%3A-,%7B,%7D,-See%20the%20XML

also maybe try to work your way back from setting it up in code then move back to config file?

Comment: @Liran ,  looks like the the pathFormat was wrong when I changed it to path and ran the code, I then got an error thrown telling me that the rollingInterval was wrong and when I changed that to just "Day" everything started working ok. - thanks

Comment: cool glad i could help :) ill post the answer so you can accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried to change to static file name? does the path exists? it seems that the configuration on the readme from their github page is a bit differnt from yours: [https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file#user-content-json-appsettingsjson-configuration:~:text=node%2C%20%3A-,%7B,%7D,-See%20the%20XML](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file#user-content-json-appsettingsjson-configuration:%7E:text=node%2C%20%3A-,%7B,%7D,-See%20the%20XML)
also maybe try to work your way back from setting it up in code then move back to config file?

Answer (score 0):

Most common mistake is that missing `Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile` nuget package. Make sure you have this installed.

Additionally, [note](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile/) for those who are visiting this question. ,

> Deprecation notice: the rolling functionality in this sink has been
> improved and merged into the Serilog.Sinks.File

In your appsettings.json file, under the Serilog node, :

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "C:\\path\\log.log",
          "rollingInterval": "Day"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```